# Magento 2: open a product tab on page load?

Tags: magento, magento2

I'm using the default product tabs accordion however I want it to open the first tab on page load, is there a way for me to do this without bodging it and writing a script for it?

So in the example below, I'd like 'Overview' to be open by default when the page is loaded:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmIj7.jpg

Thanks!

Comment: Check which one is your default tab?

Comment: @MahmoodRehman how do I check this?

Comment: there will be active like a class with the tab. And when opened which tab you see on load?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the default class : class="collapse show".